# Socket IO + PostgreSQL + PostgreSQL Adapter... driving me to hell

Tags: postgresql, socket.io, adapter

I have been swimming across the official SocketIO documentation but... I do not get it. I am working with two separated machines, both connected to another machine with a PostgreSQL DB. When I run SocketIO on the same machine, everything is fine, it works as it has to. I add the adapter and the table creation that the documentation says is all ok. I am using sequelize sooo fine, the table is created and a periodical DELETE and NOTIFY are launched to that table. Oooook. But that table, the place where magic should happen is... dry. There is no data input. NEVER. So the table is always empty and, as I can assume, this is why when I launch the other machine, SocketIO from machine 1 does not link with SocketIO from machine2, each of the machines creates their separate rooms and are never related because the data that has to do it, is not being stored in the DB. Where I am messing up?

Sequelize is used as ORM for this proyect.

Where I connect IO to the server, the adapter is launched and a table is created in the DB:

```
    const startSocketIo = function (server) {
      sequelize.query(`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS socket_io_attachments (
          id          bigserial UNIQUE,
          created_at  timestamptz DEFAULT NOW(),
          payload     bytea
      );
    `);
      io = new Server(server);
    
      io.adapter(createAdapter(sequelize));
      io.of('/').adapter.on('create-room', (room) => {
        console.warn(`room ${room} was created`);
      });
      io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
        // Verify User JWT
        const userAuth = await jwt.verifyToken(socket.handshake.auth['token']);
        if (!userAuth) {
          return socket.disconnect();
        }
```

And the other place where the "adapter" itself is called. During the "streaming" of the text. "Clients" has the array with the rooms and socket IDs created in each client login.

`const clients = await io.sockets.adapter.rooms;`

What I do not understand is that... ok, you launch it in the same machine and all is OK (because that socket data is stored in the machine's cache memory, ok) but when you try to reach that data from another server by login in the same room... nothing, because the machine that is sending that data, is not saving it outside its machine. The adapter needs to be there for that. According to the documentation, the table it creates only saves data in some specific situations so... if that is not the use I suppose it has... why is it not doing the connection between those two machines?

Comment: What is `createAdapter`?

Comment: Function from the Postgres' adapter:

`export declare function createAdapter(pool: Pool, opts?: Partial<PostgresAdapterOptions>): (nsp:any) => PostgresAdapter;`

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention you used the [postgres-adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-postgres-adapter) package. But as you can see from its documentation (and type), it takes a a `Pool` as its argument, not `sequelize`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry. But in this case, with `sequelize` you pass de connection parameters that Pool gives to the adapter. That is why the table is created correctly, isn't it?

Comment: No, the pool doesn't "give connection parameters to the adapter". It's just used as a pool, directly, calling `Pool` methods [such as `connect`](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-postgres-adapter/blob/4190f4b571cfe29c3db70c68a8250817251effd0/lib/index.ts#L159). The `sequelize` object doesn't have these, does it?

Comment: yeah, it has them. It is imported from another class that takes the connection parameters from the env. Otherwise, it could not connect and create that table inside the database. The issue is that I do not understand how you can connect two or more servers with that adapter config. I mean, the doc does not say much more.

Comment: Please show how `sequelize` is defined. Is it an instance of `Pool` from node-postgres?

Comment: "*I do not understand how you can connect two or more servers with that adapter config.*" - they communicate over the shared database, using [notifications](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) "*I mean, the doc does not say much more.*" - did you try reading the code, then?

Comment: `const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { dialect, db, user, pass, host, port, logging, timestamps, underscored } = require('@config').sequelize;

const logger = function (queryString) {
  console.debug(queryString);
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(db, user, pass, {
  host,
  port,
  dialect,
  logging: logging ? logger : false,
  define: {
    timestamps,
    underscored
  }
});
`

Comment: I do not see [`Sequelize` instances](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js~sequelize) having a `connect()` method. As I said before, you need to pass a [`new Pool`](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling) instead.

Comment: Ohh, ok, ok, now I understand what you were saying... I will try that. Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have been hitting my head with this rock for days.